# How to determine a web visitor's country of origin?

Tags: php

How to determine a web visitor's country of origin?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ip+country

Comment: possible duplicate of [IP to Country?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033/ip-to-country)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [ip2country](http://phpweby.com/software/ip2country) class for PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a better reliability and can offer not totally free solution I would recommend to you

http://worldtimeengine.com/api/ip

```
Here's an example for the IP address 195.110.64.205: 

http://worldtimeengine.com/api/ip/9d89405104e16732fa00caa1e8e6cdfd/195.110.64.205 which will return the following XML response: 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<timezone xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://worldtimeengine.com/timezone.xsd">
    <version>1.1</version>
    <location>
        <region>United Kingdom</region>
        <latitude>51.5</latitude>
        <longitude>-0.1167</longitude>
    </location>
    <time>
        <utc>2008-07-11 13:30:38</utc>
        <local>2008-07-11 14:30:38</local>
        <zone>            
            <hasDST>true</hasDST>
            <current>
                <abbreviation>BST</abbreviation>
                <description>British Summer Time</description>
                <utcoffset>+1:00</utcoffset>
                <isdst>true</isdst>
                <effectiveUntil>2008-10-26 00:00:00</effectiveUntil>
            </current>
            <next>
                <abbreviation>GMT</abbreviation>
                <description>Greenwich Mean Time</description>
                <utcoffset>+0:00</utcoffset>
                <isdst>false</isdst>
                <effectiveUntil>2009-03-29 01:00:00</effectiveUntil>
            </next>
        </zone>
    </time>
</timezone>
```