# Display flag according to Browser region

Tags: php, javascript, html, regions

On the top of my website I want a flag to show which represents the users region, i.e. browser region.

does any one have any idea on how to achieve this?

Thanks for any ideas/suggestions

edit: after some confusion, I am talking about location not language.

Comment: What is a browser region? You mean geographically?

Comment: Do you mean the visitor's country or the browser language?

Comment: yes. so if someone visited from china, it would display chinese flag, uk, uk flag etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IP to country?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033/ip-to-country)

Comment: not a duplicate, I dont want IP address, just to detect their BR (browser region) and write a script which adapts the flag shows to that of the BR

Comment: also, the question, you suggested may be a duplicate in no way shape or form resolves my issue.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "browser region". There's only browser language which isn't a good indicator of their region/country. See my answer for a solution to finding their region/country.

Comment: IE can do navigator.userLanguage

Comment: BTW, if a user changes the region of his computer and controls the browser via that computer, the region his browser is changes, therefore we get browser region.

Comment: @Ryan but that definition of "region" is the opposite of what you said you want. Do you want the language/region set in the browser, or the visitor's actual geographical location?

Comment: inherently the region of a computer is geographical, but the ability to change it gives me great scope for testing. So for that purpose i would want the region set. But, I do see your point, and its tricky! It might be more 'proper' to have the actual geopraphic location? what you think?

Comment: Geolocation based on IP is the most accurate way to determine a user's geographical location. You're right that it makes it harder to test, but unfortunately there's no way to get a computer's region through their browser. My browser's language is set to en-US but I'm in Canada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [MaxMind GeoLite Country API](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geoip_country) to determine the user's country. They also offer a [PHP module](http://www.maxmind.com/app/php) which should make it easier for you.

Once you have the user's country, you'll need to map it to a flag. Here's a free flag icon set: http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/flags/

Integration details:

```
$gi = geoip_open('GeoIP.dat', GEOIP_MEMORY_CACHE);
$country = geoip_country_code_by_addr($gi, $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
geoip_close($gi);

echo '<img src="' . $country . '.png">';
```

You'll need to read up on the PHP module but that's the quick code on how to output an image tag with the country code.

Comment: Thats what the question is, how to map it to a flag?

Comment: MaxMind API returns a country code and that flag icon set uses the same country code for their filenames. I edited my answer with some more details. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @swalk Does this work: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/eKkAT/? My alert box says HR which is correct (I'm in Croatia). Does it work for you too?

Comment: @swalk Neat `:)` I didn't know that it's that simple. Strange though why Google doesn't offer such a service.

Answer (score 0):

[infodb](http://ipinfodb.com) provide a free geolocation service - or the data required to roll your own.