# How to program different welcome pages based on country IP?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

How can I create different landing pages based on the country of the IP?  For example, people from USA should get landing page 1 and people from Spain should get landing page 2.

Answer (score 1):

use http://freegeoip.net/json/64.34.119.12 `64.34.119.12` being ip address, you will have not only country but also those field:

```
    public string ip { get; set; }
    public string country_code { get; set; }
    public string country_name { get; set; }
    public string region_code { get; set; }
    public string region_name { get; set; }
    public string metrocode { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string zipcode { get; set; }
    public string latitude { get; set; }
    public string longitude { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Page tab is really just regular web page loaded in `iframe` within Facebook Page.

Default landing tab can only be defined to all non fan visitors of Facebook, but you can use **country** and **locale** for **user** part of [signed_request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) passed to Page tab application canvas and provide different content for users from different locations/language-groups.

P.S.
Mind that you cannot really ensure that country passed by Facebook is real user country, so use detection of country based on IP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this php code

```
  <?php  $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $json = file_get_contents("http://api.easyjquery.com/ips/?ip=".$ip."&full=true");
    $json = json_decode($json,true);
    $timezone = $json[localTimeZone];?>
```